# What's the best way to determine whether a polymorphic join table is appropriate

Tags: sql, join, polymorphism

I'm trying to figure out whether I should make a polymorphic join table for a many to many relationship or whether I should make multiple join tables.

For things like comments, I always use a polymorphic join table. For relationships between users, like following on Twitter, I don't use polymorphic join tables. This is just out of habit.

Are there any good rules of thumb for deciding?

Comment: I googled "polymorphic join table" and got lots of references to rails but you've tagged this as 'sql'. Can you please define what you mean by "polymorphic join table" in the SQL context. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Traditional database design teaches that a Many:Many relationship should be devolved to two 1:Many relationships with a table in-between.

M:M = 1:M, M:1

Usually, unless the amount of data you are dealing with is immense, it can be best to normalize your database schema - it helps prevent update anomalies, Cartesian joins, and all that nasty stuff that us database designers hope to avoid.

That said, the Kimball data warehouse design method sometimes applies the star or snowflake schema, where data will be 'flaked' off into a type of mini-database. This is the type of thing that a database architect would design for an OLAP system (business analytics). I know that almost every large-scale business sytem I have worked with runs on a snowflake or star schema. For scale, we are talking 1GB plus - so it doesn't have to be huge, but beyond Microsoft Access size.

Quick links:
Database normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Database normalization (About.com): http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Kimball Group's Data Warehouse archive: http://www.kimballgroup.com/html/articles.html

The Kimball archive has some good guides about the how and when to create a warehouse.

Edit: In order to determine when you need to use a table to join two tables on the database, you can develop the database schema. This is the typical way that you lay out the design before you start coding. Developing a database schema can be a lot of work - in my program, it was taught as part of the Database Design coursework. I have added a few links for you to look at, and you may want to look up database-design here on Stack Overflow to get a greater idea. Of specific note is the Microsoft tutorial, which is pretty nice. Even if you aren't using Microsoft SQL Server, the tutorial can be helpful.

Database Schema: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema

Microsoft Database Schema Tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/express/bb403186.aspx

Comment: Super useful. How do you know when to make two distinct join tables and when to just reuse the same join table.

Comment: "normalize your relationships - it helps prevent data locks" -- I think you may have misunderstood the process of normalization. Hints: it is applied to relvars (not 'relationships') to avoid certain update anomalies ('helps prevent data locks' sounds more like an implantation consideration).

Comment: I added a bit about database schema design, which explains the fundamental reasoning for how/why/when you make distinct joining tables. Also, changed text in response to onedaywhen's comments. Typically, the more simple the design, the better - so if you can actually re-use a distinct join table, it should be valid. That said, I haven't ever really had luck doing that.